# Mikrotik simple queue

Tags: networking, mikrotik

We're a tiny newbie internet provider and we use mainly mikrotik ([SxT 5](https://routerboard.com/RBSXT5HPnDr2)) for our clients.
We use PPTP tunnels to establish connection and offer internet.

We want to limit the upload speed, so we are gonna use a simple queue to do it, the question is.  What is best to establish the queues on our edge router for all of our clients, or to implement the simple queue on each client antenna ([SxT 5](https://routerboard.com/RBSXT5HPnDr2))?

What are the pros and cons of each set up?

Many thanks

Comment: PPTP is insecure and should not be used any longer. Not an answer to your question, but worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how many clients are you talking about?

having all queues in one router is easier to config and maintain.

> But Queuing consume some CPU, resulting reduction of performance in large
>   scales.

Another disadvantage is you have to limit based on IP, but on client side you can limit based on ports. 
*(due to the fact that if you just limit by port on your side (infrastructure side) you might limit your access to the SXT client router)*

Sometimes ago, we had similar "mikrotik connected clients" (around 20 of them) and we preferred to do it on the edge side (last mikrotik conneceted to the client).